# how to get array of files of groups in resources in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am new to iphone programming. I have a scenario in which I am creating a group inside a group. that is, in project I have created

```
Resources->group1
```

in group 1 I am storing png files and I want to take all those files in one array.

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for getting all image in an array in one shot , But you could get individual images by their name  and add them in `NSMutableArray` of `UIImages`

Use below to get a image by name

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myImage.png ofType:nil]];
```

Comment: OK,So you could get images by name and add in NSMutableArray of UIImages

Comment: thats not i m looking for. i have three different groups and i want play animation from every groups randomly